# How can I disable a specific plugin in Opera (Windows)

Tags: browser-addons, opera

I'd like to disable NSAPI plugins like QuickTime and Adobe Reader in Opera.  How can I do this while leaving specific plugins I /do/ want (e.g. Flash) enabled?

Opera 10.63 on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to disable any plug in from Opera was: just write in the Opera address bar `opera:plugins` and then you will have all details for installed plugins and the ability to change and disable them.

Answer (score 2):

In opera, paste this into the address bar:

```
opera:config#Extensions|Plugins
```

That should allow you to enable/disable plugins, or view the file path of the plugin so it can be deleted from the plugins folder in opera.

Answer (score 0):

Close down Opera and add the dll filename to plugin-ignore.ini. It's in "C:\Program Files\Opera\defaults". You can goto opera:plugins in the address field to see what the filenames are for plug-ins Opera is detecting.

For Opera 11, you can just goto opera:plugins and disable the ones you want right from the UI.